# Executing a non-query requires a transaction

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, dapper

I migrated my code from WebApi2 to NET5 and now I have a problem when executing a non-query. In the old code I had:

```
    public void CallSp()
    {
        var connection = dataContext.GetDatabase().Connection;
        var initialState = connection.State;

        try
        {
            if (initialState == ConnectionState.Closed)
                connection.Open();

            connection.Execute("mysp", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (initialState == ConnectionState.Closed)
                connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

This was working fine. After I migrated the code, I'm getting the following exception:

> BeginExecuteNonQuery requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction. The Transaction property of the command has not been initialized.

So, just before calling `Execute` I added:

```
var ct = dataContext.GetDatabase().CurrentTransaction;
var tr = ct.UnderlyingTransaction;
```

And passed the transaction to `Execute`. Alas, `CurrentTransaction` is null, so the above change can't be used.

So then I tried to create a new transaction by doing:

```
using var tr = dataContext.GetDatabase.BeginTransaction();
```

And this second change throws a different exception complaining that `SqlConnection cannot use parallel transactions`.

So, now I'm in a situation where I originally had no problem to having neither an existing transaction nor can I create a new one.

How can I make Dapper happy again?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make Dapper happy again?

Dapper has no opinion here whatsoever; what is unhappy is your data provider. It sounds like *somewhere, somehow*, your `dataContext` has an ADO.NET transaction active on the connection. I can't tell you where, how, or why. But: while a transaction is active on a connection, ADO.NET providers tend to be pretty fussy about having that same transaction explicitly specified on *all* commands that are executed on the connection. This *could* be because you are somehow sharing the same connection between multiple threads, or it could simply be that something with the `dataContext` has an incomplete transaction somewhere.